# Allow Azure registered app to update it's own credentials

Tags: azure, automation, automated-tests, command-line-interface

I want to run the following commands

```
az login --service-principal -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p secret --tenant 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

```
az ad app credential reset --id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --cert "@./azureappcert.pem" --append
```

But get

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I read that Application.ReadWrite.All permission will let me do that but it will let me do that to all registered apps and I don't want that.
This is for scripted automation purposes and as I have a Microsoft Account log I can't login using the cli as myself.

I was really hoping to find a way to do this in the test script.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to login Azure Ad with Service Principal using CLI .**

I have created **Azure AD** Application as below.

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > New registration**.

[image]

Once the application is created, assign permission **Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy**  and grant it, which allows your **service principal** to **read** and **write** the metadata and properties of the specific application only.

**Open your application > API permissions > Add a permission > select Microsoft Graph > Application permission**

[image]

once add the permission, assign role to service priniciple on **subscription** level.

[image]

```
az login --service-principal -u "0c8b9fed-ab2f-xxxx-xxxxx-faf7798b38cb" -p "GwT8Q~KXhxxxxxxxxTmJQW5JsnqLdmk" --tenant "e6dxxxx-e46c-xxxx-xxx-8bxxxxxx5f73"

az ad app credential reset --id "0c8b9fed-ab2f-xxxx-xxxxx-faf7798b38cb" --cert "@./azureappcert.pem" --append
```

Successfull logged in.

[image]

If try with different application, im getting below error.

[image]

Comment: Thank-you very much for your detailed answer VenkatV, very much appreciated.
I have followed your steps but have to wait for Admin Consent on the permission.